# Prevent mod_jk to shows/append index.cfm?&_modcfmlredirected on page load

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2.4, mod-jk, lucee

I have set a virtual host configured in apache2 to proxy my cf sites to lucee/tomcat, and using mode_jk for the proxy.

Everything works fine except that on first time opening my website after a server restart the apache or lucee or the mod_jk kinda redirects to index.cfm and appending `&_modcfmlredirected` to the url.

So when I open url `cf.test` I get `cf.test/index.cfm&_modcfmlredirected`

I don't want this to happen, can anyone explain why this is happening AND how to prevent this.

BTW: After 1st hit the webpage loads fine without the above effect.

There is just a single index.cfm page containing Just one line of code which echoes date only.

virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost cf.test:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@cf.test
    ServerName cf.test
    ServerAlias www.cf.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cf.test/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.cfm
    JkMount /*.cfm ajp13_worker

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

worker-properties:

```
workers.tomcat_home=/opt/tomcat
workers.java_home=/opt/lucee/jre/bin
worker.list=ajp13_worker
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=1
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=ajp13_worker
```

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 - Fresh Install
- Apache 2.4 - default install
- PHP 7.3 default install from ondrej ppa
- mod_jp from default repository
  install libapache2-mod-jk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by updating your 'mod_cfml-valve_v1.1.09.jar' to 'mod_cfml-valve_v1.1.10.jar'.

Your can download the file from from https://github.com/viviotech/mod_cfml/tree/master/java

(Thank you Zac Spitzer)

More Info here:
https://github.com/viviotech/mod_cfml/issues/24

Comment: HI, so this is the right answer, and should work for me, but when I replace the file, The tomcat dosn't start. Will see what I can do of this